# how to compare date values in android

Tags: java, android, string, date

my `textview` need to display date of exam dead line. My `json` passes it as a string . Then i need to get current date and display the remain date on another `textviwe`

```
String date    ="2014-11-12";  //ok
Date deadline  = //how to cast string to date  
//then how to get today and subtract 
textview1.setText(today);      
int remaindays = //how to get it    
textview2.setText("You have " +remaindays  +" days to exam");
```

Comment: split the string date by "-", then create a new date with year, month and day

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to compare dates in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774871/best-way-to-compare-dates-in-android)

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. Your Question’s topics have been addressed many hundreds of times in previous Questions and Answers. Such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706). Tip: try searching for "joda" (yes, spelled correctly).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
 String date    ="2014-11-12"; 
 Date deadline; 
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
 Date strDate = sdf.parse(date);
 Long diff=-1;
 int diff=0;
 if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {
    diff=System.currentTimeMillis()-strDate.getTime();
 }
 int remaindays = (int)diff/100/60/60/24
 textview2.setText("You have " +remaindays  +" days to exam");
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Cast the string to date**

```
 String date = "2014-11-12";  
        SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
        try {  
            Date date = format.parse(date);  
            System.out.println(date);  
        } catch (ParseException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

**2. get today date**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

**3. sustraction of date**

```
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
int remaindays = (int)diff/100/60/60/24
```

Does this make sense to you?