# how to check if system date is between two times in android?

Tags: android, date

I have a **start date** = "13:45"

and an **end date** = "14:35"

Now i would like to check if the system time is between these two times, for example "14:00"

I have tried the methods **before** and **after** from the Date class but it did not worked properly

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Those are not dates, those are times.

Comment: I guess this is what you're looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774871/best-way-to-compare-dates-in-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm",
            Locale.getDefault());
    String now = format.format(new Date());
    String start = "13:45".replace(":", "");
    String end = "14:35".replace(":", "");
    boolean isBetween = Integer.valueOf(now) > Integer.valueOf(start)
            && Integer.valueOf(now) < Integer.valueOf(end);
    System.out.println(isBetween);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);

    if(current.after(start) && current.before(end)){
        //we are between
    }
```