# Displaying wrong date in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, datetime, android-recyclerview

Here I'm showing date above messages after comparison two dates. If I show dates with each item it works fine. but when I'm trying to show `Today`, `Yesterday` and `date` its always showing `date` only. Here date is not wrong, but its something getting wrong on formatting date.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date current_itemDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(chatMessage.getDateTime());

        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(chatMessage.getDateTime());
        holder.timeTextView.setText(outputFormat.format(date));
        long previousTs = 0;
        if (position > 0) {
            ChatMessage pm = chatMessages.get(position - 1);
            previousTs = simpleDateFormat.parse(pm.getDateTime()).getTime();
        }
        setTimeTextVisibility(current_itemDate.getTime(), previousTs, holder.textViewTimePeriod,
                holder.dividerTop);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm using the logic for showing `TextView` with dates or days is mentioned below. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

```
 private void setTimeTextVisibility(long now_tm, long msg_tm, TextView timeText, View dividerTop) {
    Calendar now_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar msg_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    now_calendar.setTimeInMillis(now_tm);
    msg_calendar.setTimeInMillis(msg_tm);
    boolean sameDay = now_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
            now_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            && now_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    if (msg_tm == 0) {
        timeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dividerTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (now_calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
            timeText.setText("Today");
        } else if (!sameDay) {
            timeText.setText("Yesterday");
        } else {
            timeText.setText("" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy").format(new Date(now_tm)));
        }
    } else {
        if (sameDay) {
            timeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dividerTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            timeText.setText("");
        } else {
            timeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dividerTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timeText.setText("Today");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert your date into `Millis` and then compare using these `<,>,<=,>=,==,!=`  operators or check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774871/best-way-to-compare-dates-in-android)

`.after` is used to comparing the dates

Comment: Yea, its a good approach I also improved my code snippet by using `.before` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here I want to show other developers how we can display the day before the messages like whatsapp application does.

```
 private void setTimeTextVisibility(long now_tm, long msg_tm, TextView timeText, View dividerTop) {
    Date nowDate = new Date();
    nowDate.setTime(now_tm);
    Date msgDate = new Date();
    msgDate.setTime(msg_tm);
    Calendar now_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    now_calendar.setTimeInMillis(now_tm);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar msg_calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    msg_calendar.setTimeInMillis(msg_tm);
    if (msg_tm == 0) {
        timeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dividerTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (DateUtils.isToday(now_calendar.getTimeInMillis())) {
            timeText.setText("Today");
        } else if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) - now_calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
            timeText.setText("Yesterday");
        } else
            timeText.setText("" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy").format(new Date(now_tm)));
    } else {
        if (msgDate.before(nowDate)) {

            boolean sameDay = now_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                    now_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                    && now_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == msg_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Log.e("YESTERDAY", (now.get(Calendar.DATE) - msg_calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) + "");
            if (sameDay) {
                timeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dividerTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                timeText.setText("");
            } else {
                timeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                dividerTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (DateUtils.isToday(now_calendar.getTimeInMillis())) {
                    timeText.setText("Today");
                } else if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) - now_calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
                    timeText.setText("Yesterday");
                } else {
                    timeText.setText("" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy").format(new Date(now_tm)));
                }
            }
        } else {
            timeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dividerTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            timeText.setText("");
        }
    }


}
```