# How to compare time exist between two times in android

Tags: java, android

String time1="09-00 AM"; String time2="07-00 PM";

String date=  15-09-2017 04:04:33

```
String time1 = "09-00 AM";
    String time2 = "07-00 PM";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS");
            Date time1 = df.parse("09-00 AM");
            Date time2 = df.parse("07-00 PM");
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            sf.format(date);
            TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
            Date c = shiftTimeZone(date, tz1);
            System.out.println("Format :   " + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS").format(c));

            System.out.println(time1 + "" + time2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can I compare that date time is exist between time1 and 
time2 please suggest how I can check this, I am not able to split time or merge with date.

For that I am trying to Convert time1 and time2 in Date object in HH:mm:SS

Comment: Where is the time which you want to check if exists between `time1` and `time2`?

Comment: ew SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS").format(c) lies between time1 and time 2

Comment: Your question is poorly worded.  _Which_ dates do you want to use for the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.after` method to compare two dates
 check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952524/displaying-wrong-date-in-recyclerview-adapter/45952644#45952644) for more details

Comment: but first how i will convert time in to date formate of time1 and time 2

Comment: the best way is get Milli seconds of your time and thn compare

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
            Date time1 = df.parse("09-00 AM");
            Date time2 = df.parse("07-00 PM");
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            //converts date to required format
            String current = sf.format(date);
            Date currentTime = df.parse(current);
            // TODO COMPARE currentTime with time1 or time2 as per your need

            System.out.println(time1 + "" + time2 +" " + currentTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Unparseable date: "09-00 AM"  exception coming

Comment: @Adevelopment try now and if gets any unexpected output use hh:mm a and try