# How to find the last day of month with MM/YY as date (in string format)?

Tags: java, android, date

I am attempting to validate an expiry date for a given payment card (in my Android App). The user enters the expiry date using this month picker: https://github.com/premkumarroyal/MonthAndYearPicker

The date is stored in my EditText in MM/yy format. I now want to ensure that the date is not before todays date. To do so, i am trying to find out the last day of the month chosen and comparing it to today's date to see if the chosen day is before todays date (hence expired).

I was wondering how I can do this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
cardExpiryDate.getText().toString()
```

Gets the date selected by the user and converts into a string so its in the following format -> MM/yy

EDIT:
It isn't a duplicate of the suggested link as that link compares two dates (which include days) whereas I have to convert a string in MM/yy form to dd/MM/yy (so that dd is the last date of that month) and then compare it to today's date..
I hope that made sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to compare dates in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774871/best-way-to-compare-dates-in-android)

Comment: How can MM/YY represent the last day of the month??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this question by comparing just the months of the user input date and todays date instead of comparing the entire date.

Answer (score 0):

## `YearMonth` class

Parse your string input as a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/uu" ) ;
YearMonth expiry = YearMonth.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Capture today’s date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Get the year-month of today.

```
YearMonth currentYearMonth = YearMonth.from( today ) ;
Boolean isExpired = currentYearMonth.isAfter( expiry )  ;
```

Notice that we don’t care about the last day of month you mentioned in the Question.